# How can I execute a javascript function when the user tries to leave the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, chat

I'm looking for a way to automatically set the user status as "offline" and to do this I need to execute a JavaScript function, unless there are any better ideas out there. How can I run a function when the user tries to navigate away from the page? I know there is a way to have a message box appear so there should be a way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `unload` method to call an `ajax` method. Note the important `async` attribute which says to the browser that it needs to wait the HTTP response before closing the window (to ensure that your server received the "offline" status).

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "setoffline.php",
        async: false
    });
});
```

Comment: I am not sure I would block the act of closing the window. It would probably suffice to just send the async request and let the window close. Then, on the server you can have a timeout for how long a user is considered "online". Just my 2 cents, though.

Comment: So when Async is set to false it makes sure the server revived the status or vice versa? Will this example run the PHP script entirely then close? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @JeremyHeiler how could I create a timeout?

Comment: @Pete: That depends on what you are using on the server side and how you are storing session state.

Comment: @Pete, the `unload` event doesn't work with assync functions because the browser always closes before completing the Request. So the server never receives nothing. Because of it the code only works with the `assync: false`. But doesn't takes care about it, this kind of Request happens so fastly that your end user never realizes it (many sites do it and you never realized, no?).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this one.

```
<body onbeforeunload="return RunOnClose()">
function HandleOnClose() {
    //do your magic here
    return true;
}
```

Comment: but I will recommend @ErickPetru's solution instead.

Answer (score 0):

The follow event fires when the window "unloads":

```
window.onbeforeunload
```

I have paired that with an onload event handler in a similar scenario, where I had a row in my DB tracking the user Last Login Session.  It had an "entered" date when they login / come to the site and I would set the "Last seen" DateTime on the onunload event, but I was also clearing the "Last seen" date time on the "onload" of the page.

So, the last time they close any page, the "Last Seen" Date is set and it persists